# How to exclude files from csproj using a props file (NuGet)

Tags: msbuild, nuget, csproj

I am working on creating a NuGet package which will include some target/props files for our organization.

One of those props files has the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- Other stuff that works... -->

  <None Remove="SomeFolder\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The Xml tag works perfectly fine when I copy/paste it into the csproj file itself, but when I pull in the NuGet Package which includes that Xml tag as part of the props file, the **SomeFolder** is not excluded/removed.

I know that the props file is being loaded because the other parts of the same `ItemGroup` in the props file work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to ordering of imports and evaluation. Use the `DefaultItemExcludes` property instead:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);SomeFolder\**\*</DefaultItemExcludes>
</PropertyGroup>
```